# Beginner who needs help making sense of how function perameters are defined

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I am new to javaScript and have been self learning by watching youtubers walk-through 'beginner friendly' projects but I'm having a problem wrapping my head around parameters and how they are defined in a function.

The project is a simple image corousel and theres a certain arrow function I can't quite follow:

```
const slideWidth = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;


slides.forEach((slide, index) => { 
    slide.style.left = slideWidth * index + 'px';
});
```

So I understand the function is using the size of the slides to determine how far to move the images to the left but I don't understand how the function understands that 'index' means the array number because the function does not define this.

I've tested this code out and it works, I just really want to understand HOW it works. I know this is a simple concept but I am a true novice who is really trying to break into the world of JavaScript, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're over thinking it, that's just how forEach works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#syntax You don't need to know "how the function understands that 'index'". It's just how that function is defined.

Comment: Documentation, you need to read it for things you do not understand.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not discussions. Please if the code works, there is not point using StackOverflow

Comment: @surge10 No, Stack Overflow is not only for broken code. A question that asks for an explanation of working code is perfectly fine, if it wasn’t a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to explain how it works is with a simple dummy example.

The concept is called a callback:

```js
function myForEach(callback) {
  const item = "something";
  const index = 3;
  const array = [10, 20, 30];

  // invoke the callback with three arguments passed through
  callback(item, index, array);
}

myForEach((slide, index) => {
  console.log(slide); // something (item)
  console.log(index); // 3 (index)
});
```

So the "real" `forEach` takes a callback function as an argument and iterates the array that the `forEach` is "attached" to, then invokes the callback for each iteration with three arguments passed through to the callback:

1. the item from the current iteration of the array
2. the index for the current iteration
3. and the entire array

Hope it explains it just a little.